# Angular tag on Stack Overflow out of date?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) description is as follows:

> *AngularJS is an open-source JavaScript framework. Its goal is to augment browser-based applications with Model–View–Controller (MVC)
>   capability*

But, according to the Angular website, it is now MVW:

> *AngularJS is what HTML would have been, had it been designed for building web-apps. Declarative templates with data-binding, MVW, MVVM,
>   MVC*

Also, [Igor Minar declared](https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2) Angular 'officially' MVW:

> I hereby declare AngularJS to be MVW framework - Model-View-Whatever.
>   Where Whatever stands for "whatever works for you".

**Conclusion**

I think we should update the angular tag to make it more up-to-date.

Comment: Make it so. Suggest an edit to the tag wiki.

Comment: @Oded - Does any privilege require to suggest edit to the tag wiki? Or you can suggest tag wiki edit with 1 reputation?

Comment: @hims056 - checked. No privilege associated to these, as they are peer reviewed.

Comment: Ok, ty, i'll do that. I didn't even know i could do that